# Weird issue with json encode

Tags: php, json

I have `charset=utf8` set as a parameter for my PDO connection. When I try to `json_encode` an array I get back, for some reason it returns a bunch of `�͝��` characters. However, if I `print_r` the array before hand then I encode it, it works fine. This only occurs with some results, others work just fine. Is this because there are some characters in my data that are not UTF-8 or something?

note: I'm on php 5.3.28 and cannot update to 5.4 to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

edit: `json_last_error` also returns no errors.

edit: This is what I am doing that returns the jumbled text.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT userid, first_name, last_name, email FROM table WHERE event=?');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['id']));
$responses = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode{$responses);
```

output:

```
�F�z�9��(Ҙ�i-9�o���k�ʚ���J20��b���䄚���U�r��*q��w�*7 C�`|"�q��K�0d��(=�~��U��LS�o{i�%��#S����� ��$0�{�80���B� �̇�5&���Z���x#��   h�͂�� ��C�Oۡ����x@���^�ws�s��� )#)U8KZt����X�%���i�+�{�լ�p�I�Q����j��]�� R��u;?�''yU\����\�D��:!D�y�q��M!�+�~/o�B�U�^h���������*�KP�,���'�ѤR)���@�n�xX������;i�jk ���O����X���Xp�M���;��w�S1VP����V�Z�c#wbC5�cDM�Y9��֓�W^u�xd�\5�E
```

json_encode then bin2hex:

```
��][��Fr�+>~��.�K_�<�Wٲe)�vs�l�Ng ���c��俧���@v���ؒe{�B�P]�ե[������eS-���oӉ��4~��o�ˍ[�0��5M���Ъ��n��{)׮Z�H���E��`S�����0���ӈQ}W�ˆ��,n7esJ��I����bUݕ��^s�*��qg�������u ?�Tۭ;�����n]��_��;�@?K'�h�����զd��7nsJ������Z�A��w����&�j}�6wJu|��ʇS��q�>H��h6S���w��qyܔ�r�H��_]��(Wj�0ٖ�MU3&�ͮ)ǈ�n��}�v�*N^�\f�d����S���=c�Ϳ���s}Jy��۝k��.Hy2N��>�������'�c�ş78)�s�.�棯D�N������j˗W�q��0/�v)��t4�fL��W��:����ƾ!M*�I�l�Lm|J~�_4%ɻ�f�������w�u��MN鎚r��z\�7L"#�#q,Q�͘�x��V������7��Y��"N�H�l�FQ�5��l9N\�e�~�v�6M�a4�T)[��߯�   W[0��3�v8Yy'���[�k��b�r�o�  �I@wU���*�K����qSmw��v ?rܒ�|pQ* &7� S��bև���`�r���)������X&?K����@����z�Y�.Uy��6ɣ��s)�:X���-�0m�    +��k��㲨V�s�@�f�q҇9 K� �f��§�+F���k��?λ����ĉ�������F�݊C�����i4ILX!�x�}M��I���-7k�yyJ�O�cd��  [G�U�w@���upÏ�o�~XRE�2U|_��\a~���}W_@��8�J�u̼�k�ܸ�x^�w�?�QT��g�j:N��)%^�s�i&a���*Կ�����l�>��2�����=�fo��G�������퐙������6g�_�Ø�8��F�8�2�|_�ӟ�5����]H�@u�8�ڹ7d�����ü�a<�� ��G3h/�>G��(;����yn�a����x�� ��0�_tU�����X�]��"�1�U�L2�������8�d/j�7u��i��Y���0#����7��j���S�����[��a�35o�A)FhLY&�6�r;X]@x_��$��W���}��D��]�D���*o��<��Ub��|��Mwy^|�a���������d�rf�����f��)��8g׎7��a��ɣ/�����,f��?+��+�o��\F~� �    ���L��� �_W����5������fU����U�P�x��^l-�ݯn�X�r�=O��<1*����W;д��c���|��M��0�b˰��,Ve�s뭻��ڭ� C ���m�    f�*c��ܽWw����W�%�l��G¹���b�-���X��� Y�    d�n�����m   S�'q2b����ª�q�VK�"���'0��=*�N#f�F���WM�p%�Q:b��U ���_�\����y����/�c4��S�x.�c��y�綃mUZ!�ǣt���O,�.o����4>~��/�=��pM��_����͚��K�+�o�n�� �x�d'�  ����{��V4���($�q�)���l>��Y:c�ݹŎ�2fb��!�y����ߖ�����Նk��������Е�����Wƈ��~^����0w�~��K�8��׹՜�fQ�����ԚIl�c��/?\83�̊��IrR���~%��,<3��oݼ줪�h 1���;���+K�VA�Lg3m��]' ����=����F��e0q:���@�Y�o�������U�����S%�و�Wn�-��S&��7Bt'��5g��v2$�MGΫr�H���$���c��t��}�@  (a��.;���F*噢s�R�on�ʜ��8��0`�f��h̟p�q���3^Ջ�����ƕ������n�ǭ�"�l��nw3WA��I��Tw���&h=� u`(Ny`�1qV�;e��u�� �t)�:��J�3���=Ϡ���S۪p���gWmݯ� ��Ϣ�E=�(b���Q}ul}��1���8}�I�GCf]f/y����XqE�o1�MÄӉ�sfY�A�թy�P�j�H �[.���d<��:|XB�瘥�.ۡG�xSo����b�F�ءM��b4�S�v�����!���� �v�'<�{��T��;L�0�Es�d��H�1�f�ϛjſ��'�;�Wk?.-��'3Y�h���L@��8��͢ �⩂p��&���6������'�Ք��Es�ប�o�q���܁���~�N���\f`܍��p6w �+�p1�쩎�S�� @TwS�l�~��ia��,������ͨ\���P�<=�3)i�`�$�S�@C��o;�Zߺ]�����~�q���~-�cަ�c�[U~�SU���|N�4��������2��*�[���;��>�k�\i0�@��Xiy9��VE�3�~ ���N��F�Ef6�5o����� n������c�sQ|�(�3����������wrw� �`� c�Y+�����7��Xt���Uy�WB�-�<<�FW�W�N4�E¯��x6f�{��f8��cM�`�˦��/�nwa�e*��s�ZQ���F+��a.J*;�`_N���� ٪~WB���ޥT���f��;'�NF���dS��<_��D�d�k�iL� 0&�����h�!���v�r�[�S��x�F�ݳ,��έxqBe�9��m@(��?�<DQ���s��ݾ):,m�1�����#'���ێ���)��y�̔-��-�&�K^*������|zf#;ռ�p@ 3�,��h���z�uv�Y�����NRel�v�[D$+�������+�F���W��[�p�_�fw�>MP�&ܗ�G��:M1�]� ���s=F�82(��0���%>��׶p�.���$3��4\���������{�����S�]S%7����0�)�n��t&��~p3+��Ѧ����4K-���<��O`�ּ��p����E�y�1��]G'/�v��!�(���l��"�?eI   �4R���x����4 ���4�i�T�p@OMB��SJ�a���ɭ�%��Y��+LB����q�yG�K|���}?�%yg��9x?\%��u��<�3�?I^�K��ā�8zR�cA�/ h�)C�k����"xS���W�FY�$��)��D^� �ey"�.�(���uA�.�Jlڹ���q���(�� ��Ɂv�g�����6 s��d�Td����?M���,ܹ$�4%�ZQ � g�n���F��KS���5g����qա�ؠ<���i.�a�p�J��$%��B[�Z��=ϊ�8���k\zbg�\+��u�p�)��s�m{�n˵�Q��d\�G�?a;QX��V�z�%&�W�<    j=<*JUO~�J���]��_a�M���o��GJ�sz�� ��"�6 #�آ����D#ե�w{d~B ��JV�u�f*l�    ��l�S��������I�ZԗW�At�@=�|3ڮVX�Wp?Kz_䠠u��:���zj5��ª��Z���w�^�=�JЏG �i���Z��6�� ,D�"G K��;�)�� r�|���H~=t"�PO����?!L������ΰ�KI�E䌷.�ȹ�I�t��O�j�X�>J����=�P�£@�,�k�R�GV���9���� ���� �h=��5~dz��\Xe���>ڎȆ�BX���b�34���H��3�Ĳ�k����qMI��`��0�>P"lu��[x��U�WU�!�oAou� ��茞a�}ћ���{L�0���KH_u��%쒀n��M���c![�S���9"   Ze���������.�'T���|��P�&H��I�t��b�A�V�dvo��0%�@h�����1C�UrKe����\kD�b&�(�J�%��5Ħ���N�6?�Mg�MK�b:�����X9A����������  -ӹ�$�o[����vI����6C�+�{��QDlHلe/t   ����\�"/��z��G���1����@�m1����K�y��.����0� #4�/�&��ɢ�)ŷ���e��9��?���XEQ����Fgk�"�� ���@}IJ��8�(���O���u&�� ��ı�a�s�kG0�� 躙?�k�j�|��\��0�� �s����T~]���O���^����|t���5��X̔jha\���I�8MJ*����rx~~�\�=Hj1��"J5���6�����;�ߪ�۠�+B�a�o)ZH�����.�����$����;|�B����@��qml��[:�3���~1���d���?�S�~����Al�hU�X8�EN"I�N����+;<�h�3!k�Z$�����#�Ҵ�{hx�=r?�m)ӿ�w�2GMs����㼶+ASM�J�>+����yư-'��cA�R�%��:N��)'�����R{��V�(��G��r��ƨ-�)v�N$I���+ua������0��[�2!Zε��;�r����%!-/a���e1����X�{鳵#E�!U�hu������>x��,(q-���!�� 1��/�H�8Y6��~O�8�~8%h3������.��}�mM1�@sF͜�E���:^��/d��^��n_ݙ:�d>�7\��H���_~v��Ovg��&�T����-�C/b٫e�R�b.v-F��S����C�%�x31k5���U��(͕��@���)�o�o!:����"�D��R�;�B��rUM�1!q��!�=���+U�O���W�̍9�ۋ���7���S�pI�C������J�:��m����ee4�H����V.-� k��ӆ�.(�k-�h��,��EX��Y�>'���mFK����rO���9y�$���3;�����!�u�ߧӑ���Z,����I�_{|�=�K��V���c'��^3 =�Ƭ#f�m��(��͈��:��>���R�9�;SKR\�TO�I6<��"�J1���^��zJY��kv�s�x���m�R���}8�=89Y6_A ��2��>F�K:�[α�C ;����S��"�Ԝ�V�y�|��[Tx�|�O���=~Tzu ߁:�q��#��F��G_)�@ m�s� ��;N�oC�*q��[ľ!��#�H�S)g�Y����X���1F���(60O�2{Ϗ��x�j~���#kQ��z��|B��V��ϲךT������tQD�֣�p$��}z�\��SW~ߤ�S��� V���f�5������c_�uR��k�{v�H�k[�ɂ���*e���-��ڸZ�Qe��@�w���� �"V���x!FG�}��Y��V��*�,�����eA¨���Z�G�)V�! ��l�G,���9�H�GѻI}��y�Ӟ3)v[����r2*<����� ����?B��=�ϯ�i�n��H{��9O�]S�ړA;�}�M������̻:��8'$�!��is�_��~��v+s��xW�������u j�cX�=h �F熟�p�^S��w���o�Sk<��   ��G�� e��������e�$���5�}dؼ���s�;�L�����%���]4m�Rڧ��dD-�Y�Ƕ�Ό��^��L0R ��~W`��>/c} "m���ׁ��t�iϷ \՟�����W�T����ͺ�|����G�����s��@����   QP|�������)R���$�豾���&�� �k;p��Ky�-�V��*�잾��т콮������Z��6��'ͩJ�����v}�y-����=�R���:��G� ;[,��eߞ�"���d�����}a_�#�Z���;qO�O�1� J�ٚ�x^�6|:��t�U�W�\c���W�s��~P�=癖���o1`�̑�-")i'ۓ(#&�n�0z�z�a��xfϙ�R��8�_�_�F��n7��u���n��wńU&�=ˇ>����X�= 2��6���y�~��$Te��b0Ѫx���}�qz�Y{�ε���9H�� �{ɧ�-y�[��P���H��׽��>K����K5"E�&�b��Z���Cl��~i����j±q�(�.)����>�s畖=���pǔ~�� �!Z�Rl��3j�$�0?B�%x#�����9�O�� �V��{���iDw��xKgJ)oC���� �(h9#��b���8R1�=��"��Љ�����UFӨ�)]�m�E�W'sp׷��kV���EB�a�w�P�Tӎ��ԕ�Ñ�B �%s���+ao�3�ɹ�/  ��R�}.�{��ߏ�Xڣ.��8Ed��ЎV!S�+�w3���yz�aw~���n�g��?ŻH�M�y��w��⎤Cϥ��$�u�`ڙ��퇙q/���u�yi|����$w��Iu�)w����Y�ڸ{O�H�}#�i����b̲ կ<�Z�Gm͵�e�2��Ò��C�g�=��e��������Vh�K����q��U����i��^2��O5  �\�S|�C�ɞ{� Ɛ��X��N�5�lB�!�I�tl���;�Z-� �X>���yd��L�Cld%Y?�F ��=j�p����찆{L���w�9�w _ڗB�������^|�)�e#�̥��Nj��}'��I'Y�u����n¢b�[�چ��>d���㙅���l��ɽ�J��=���6XIW�NJ��8��F�������,�N�s��^��_a�w;�K���P�f�w�(�I�]����������z�G��#�x���V>f��+JVb�0�����ZF}�xj�ߝ���)��w���=eQ�P�u����E�jR��lN甆���}NSXc*�OJ��@I�l ������"���M%RF���!�}�>E��F�:7x��4�H��K�}��s-i�!y#�w���=dX���2�'[�Т��):X��Ǚ����+��̩_�    �QJ�����ǹ֟{}�Ɋ�wM]~V�}�V$e�hk�,���دC'��9���3�5fB�ۮ��ڏ��I����8�>�s���;p�c������Dz���qV/ �/R*��wO��A��v��}_�����ϸ[U81��sm��>}���>䛐���K1FO�S�H}���Y�@{���ǚ�$y�Z�'j�x����������ϟ���3��A��Ю���@���#��������Q��ߕ�����"�9R��=�&~";3S�={�8�b�w��������ΕR�W'~e
```

Comment: Please provide a full, minimal working example of what exactly you're doing and what exactly the results are. There's no information for us to really go on here. However: if your data wasn't UTF-8, `json_encode` would return `null`. So at least that should be working.

Comment: @deceze ok I did that.

Comment: And what's the result exactly? And possibly also what's the input exactly?

Comment: @deceze like I said, the result is just a bunch of random garbage data. I put it above. the input is just an array of id's, names and emails.

Comment: That's pretty darn weird, since `json_encode` should exclusively spit out ASCII chars. Are you interpreting the result as UTF-16 or something? Can you show this text as `bin2hex()`?

Comment: @deceze Ok i added it. Its first the results of `echo json_encode(...)` then the results of echo `bin2hex(json_encode(...))`

Comment: @deceze also I found somewhere a suggestion to add `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');` to my php code. This actually works but it returns my json to jquery as an object. I guess I can work with that. it's pretty weird though since it doesn't work with `text/html` replacing `application/json`, and I already have `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in my htaccess

Comment: If even `bin2hex` is messed up, you're simply looking at the result with the wrong charset interpretation. There's nothing wrong with `json_encode`!

Comment: @deceze How would I find the right charset? I have set utf-8 in my htaccess and when opening up the db, so I am not sure what more I could do?

Comment: Look at your raw HTTP response headers, what charset is being suggested to the browser (debug/development tools of the browser help).